# Write in a file with Python 3 & unicode

Tags: file, unicode, python-3.x, encode

Here is my code:

```
import codecs
filename = "worst.txt"
file = open(filename, "r",encoding='utf-8')
lines = file.readlines()
texte = ""
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    texte += line
file.close()
print(texte)
texte = texte.split(";")
print(texte)
filename = "oudean.html"



file = open(filename, "w",encoding='utf-8')



file.write("<html><body>\r\n")
for t in texte :
        print(t)
        file.write("""<img src="ouedan.jpg"><br>\r\n""")
        file.write("""Une déclaration à faire ?<br>Besoin d'encouragements?<br>Notre brigade d'élite beat agent est là pour vous aider.<br>Faites appel à nous en appelant le  06 et nous accourrons vous encourager dans l'instant.<br>N hésitez pas.<br>Et pour vous aider durant cette soirée, voilà une accroche a tester, succès garanti :<br>%s<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>"""%t)
file.write("</body></html>\r\n")
file.close()
```

But I gives me:

> Une dÃ©claration Ã  faire ? Besoin d'encouragements? Notre brigade
>   d'Ã©lite beat agent est lÃ  pour vous aider. Faites appel Ã  nous en
>   appelant le 06 et nous accourrons vous encourager dans l'instant. N
>   hÃ©sitez pas. Et pour vous aider durant cette soirÃ©e, voilÃ  une
>   accroche a tester, succÃ¨s garanti :

So how to write in a file with unicode string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your symptoms look like regular a "UTF-8 as latin-1" problem.

Have you checked what encoding is used on the software that you are using to view that file? I'd say that the problem is not necessarily in your python code but in the viewer.

If you create a file with your example text `Une déclaration à faire...` using UTF-8 encoding and then read that file interpreting the contents using encoding ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252, then the result is shown as the output you described: `Une dÃ©claration Ã faire...`.

Also, in python 3 the default source encoding is UTF-8. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/

Answer (score 0):

It seems python does not understand what encoding your source is in. You have to tell it, either by using byte-order mark (preferred) or via declaring the type with special comment in first or second line. So:

1. tell your editor to store byte-order-mark in the source, or, if it can't do that
2. put a comment at the beginning containing (IIRC) `encoding: utf-8`.